# Why is the Nginx PHP Unit ignoring the root parameter in this configuration file?

Tags: nginx, php, wordpress, nginx-unit

I'm trying to move `example.com` from a multisite WordPress installation into its separate WordPress installation folder. I've already setup a separate database and created a new file `wp-config.php` for the new WordPress installation with the information needed to start the new installation. The problem is that when I switch the parameter `root` in the Nginx configuration file from the old multisite installation folder to the new one, the old website is still loaded by Nginx.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/example.com.conf**

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen      [::]:80;
    server_name example.com;
    root        /var/www/wordpress_exanoke/; # <-- this was changed to point to
                                               #     the new single site installation
                                               #     the old multisite installation
                                               #     folder is /var/www/wordpress

    if ($scheme = "http") {
        rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @index_php;
    }

    location @index_php {
        proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8090;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location /wp-admin {
        index index.php;
    }

    location ~* .php$ {
        try_files        $uri =404;
        proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.1:8091;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen [::]:443 ssl; #ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/chained.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/domain.key; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

    ssl_client_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/cloudflare.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;
}
```

Comment: You say this is WordPress? That is PHP. But your configuration uses `proxy_pass` to pass to some apps on ports 8090 or 8091. What are these apps? Where is your PHP configuration?

Comment: @MichaelHampton the configuration file is a modified version of the one that appears [here](https://www.nginx.com/blog/installing-wordpress-with-nginx-unit/) in the step 3 under "**Configuring NGINX Open Source**"

Comment: @MichaelHampton you are right I didn't change the file `wordpress.config` under the new single-site installation folder. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that you are using NGINX Unit to serve your PHP code. In that case you also need to change the document root in the configuration file that you provide to unit, and resubmit the API call to reload the new configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you restart the `nginx` server?

`nginx` requires restart to load the new configuration.

Use command `sudo nginx -t` for testing if your configuration is correct.

And `sudo systemctl restart nginx` to restart.

Comment: Yes, I restarted the server.